# javascript program to check if a string is palindromes not returning false

Tags: javascript

I wrote this bit of code a a part of an exercise to check weather or not a string is palindromes. They program is working correctly in terms of checking the string but it does not return false when the string is not palindromes. What am I doing wrong? thanks

```
//convert the string to array
var stringArr = [ ];
var bool;
function palindrome(str) {
  // make lowercase
  var lowerCase = str.toLowerCase();
  //remove numbers, special characters, and white spaces
  var noNumbers = lowerCase.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
  var noSpecials = noNumbers.replace(/\W+/g, " ");
  var finalString = noSpecials.replace(/\s/g, '');
  stringArr = finalString.split("");

    if (stringArr.sort(frontToBack)==stringArr.sort(backToFront)) {
       bool = true;  
    }
    else {
       bool= false;

    }
  return bool;
}
function frontToBack (a,b) {return a-b;}
function backToFront (a,b) {return b-a;}

palindrome("eye");
```

Comment: I think this question is more suited for codereview? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

`if (stringArr.sort(frontToBack)==stringArr.sort(backToFront)) {` is your problem.

In JavaScript, the `sort` method updates the value of the variable you are sorting. So in your comparison, once both sort's have run, both end up with the same value (since the second sort, effectively overrides the first).

For example.

```
var a = [1,7,3];
a.sort();
console.log(a); // will print 1,3,7
```

Edit: had a quick test, I think eavidan's suggestion is probably the best one.

Edit2: Just put together a quick version of a hopefully working palindrome function :)

```
 function palindrome(str) { return str.split("").reverse().join("") == str;}
```

Comment: thanks this helped! my solution still does not apply to these two cases: FIRST: palindrome("_eye") should return true. SECOND: palindrome("1 eye for of 1 eye.") should return false

Comment: Mines really just a sample, add back in your lowercasing & unwanted character stripping and it should do what your after :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because string subtraction yields `NaN`, which means both sorted arrays are the same as the original.

Even if you did convert to ASCII coding,  you sort the entire string, then for instance the string `abba` would be sorted front to back as `aabb` and back to front as `bbaa`. (**edit:** and also what Carl wrote about `sort` changing the original array. Still - sort is not the way to go here)

What you should do is just reverse the string (using `reverse` on the array) and compare.

Answer (score 0):

You might do as follows;

```js
var isPalindrome = s => { var t = s.toLowerCase()
                                   .replace(/\s+/g,"");
                          return [].slice.call(t)
                                   .reverse()
                                   .every((b,i) => b === t[i]);
                        };

console.log(isPalindrome("Was it a car or a cat I saw"));
console.log(isPalindrome("This is not a palindrome"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       function pal()
        {
            var x=document.getElementById("a").value;

            //input String 

            var y="";

           //blank String 

            for (i=x.length-1;i>=0;i--)
          //string run from backward

                {

                    y=y+x[i];
       //store string last to first one by one in blank string 

                }

            if(x==y)

          //compare blank and original string equal or not 

                {

                    console.log("Palindrome");

                }

            else

                {

                    console.log("Not Palindrome ");

                }

        }
```