# Palindrome algorithm

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

so I feel like I'm gettin close with this but I'm just missing out on something.

This algorithm should check if a specific word/sentence is the same reading backwards. Apparently all non-alpha num chars should be ignored for the comparison.

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var pure = str.replace(/[\W_]/g, "").toLowerCase();
  var arr = [];
  arr = pure.split("").reverse();
  var x = arr.join("");
  
  if(str === x){
    return true;
  }
      return false;  
}

palindrome("eye");
```

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: What's your question? This isn't a site to get people to write it for you, or give general feedback; it's for specific questions.

Comment: Just for lazy people :p ; Here is a link that could help you (First on google)    http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/determine-if-a-string-is-a-palindrome.html

Comment: A close duplicate of [javascript program to check if a string is palindromes not returning false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730416/javascript-program-to-check-if-a-string-is-palindromes-not-returning-false/39730864#39730864)

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare reversed string with `pure` instead of `str` although you can make it much simpler by removing unnecessary variable and `if` statement.

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  // remove non-word character including `_`
  var pure = str.replace(/[\W_]/g, "").toLowerCase();
  // split into character array, reverse it and join the array
  var x = pure.split("").reverse().join("");
  // compare the strings
  return pure === x;
}

console.log(palindrome("eye"));
console.log(palindrome("ey e"));
console.log(palindrome("ey"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done recursively

```
function palindrome(s)
{
   if (s.length<2)
     return true;
   return (s[0]==s[s.length-1]) && palindrome(s.substr(1,s.length-2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function palindrome(str) {
  var pure = str.replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, "").toLowerCase();

  var arr = [];
  arr = pure.split("").reverse();
  var x = arr.join("");
  if(pure === x){
   return true;
  }
  return false;  
}
```

Comment: So instead of \W you can just specify what ranges to include?

Comment: actually \W is equal to [^0-9a-z_].

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
function palindrome(str) {
 if(str == str.split("").reverse().join("")) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}

console.log(palindrome('eye'));
```

**Note** It only works with simple ASCII characters

Edit with ASCII characters only:

```
function palindrome(str) {
 pure = str.replace(/[\W_]/g, "").toLowerCase();
 if(pure == pure.split("").reverse().join("")) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}

console.log(palindrome('eye'));
```

Comment: why do you need the `if` ? just use `return str == str.split("").reverse().join("");`

Comment: Very true. I was keeping the OP's coding standard.

Answer (score 0):

You might do this as follows as well...

```js
var isPalindrome = s => { var t = s.toLowerCase()
                                   .replace(/\s+/g,"");
                          return [].slice.call(t)
                                   .reverse()
                                   .every((b,i) => b === t[i]);
                        };

console.log(isPalindrome("Was it a car or a cat I saw"));
console.log(isPalindrome("Was it a car or a cab I saw"));
```